# Sending mail with pdf attachment with laravel 10 mail documentation fromData method

Tags: laravel

I want to send email using laravel documentation method of attaching pdf.  I see other methods of sending pdf directly in the controller with function(){...} but i dont want to use that. In laravel documentation, there is fromData method that can be used to send pdf that is not saved in the database.

Controller.php

```
 $customer = Customer::findOrFail(session('customerid'));

$pdf = PDF::loadView('PDF\customerappointmentpdf', compact(['data', 'customer', 'appointment']));


       
        $mailData =[
            'customer' => $customer,
            'pdf' => $pdf,
        ];
        Mail::to($customer)->queue(new CustomerAppointment($mailData));
```

In my CustomerAppointment controller,

```
class CustomerAppointment extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

   

     public $mailData;
  
    public function __construct($mailData)
    {
        $this->pdf = $mailData['pdf'];
        $this->customer = $mailData['customer'];
    }

  
    public function envelope()
    {
        return new Envelope(
            
            subject: 'Customer Appointment',
        );
    }

   
    public function content()
    {
        return new Content(
            markdown: 'emails.customerappointment',
            with:
                $this->pdf
               
        );
    }

   
    public function attachments()
    {
        return [
            Attachment::fromData(fn () => $this->pdf->output(), 'customerappointmentpdf.pdf')
            ->withMime('application/pdf'),
            
        ];
    }
}
```

but i get error  Undefined property: App\Mail\CustomerAppointment::$pdf

Comment: You defined `public $mailData;`, but you never use `$this->mailData`... Similarily, you never defined `public $pdf;` or `public $customer;`, but you try to use those as `$this->pdf` and `$this->customer`. This is basic OOP in PHP; remove `public $mailData;` and add `public $pdf;` and `public $customer;`, then your code should work as written.

Comment: @ Tim Lewis, thanks but i get this error "Serialization of 'DOMDocument' is not allowed". I have tried to figure it out but was not possible for me